# Typescript Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'A[] & string[]' (should be 'A[] | string[]')

Tags: typescript

I am trying to assign a `string[]` to an object that contains either `string[]` or an array of type `A[]` like this:

```js
// some arbitrary type A
type A = {
  valueOne: string,
  valueTwo: string,
};

type Container = {
  a: readonly A[],
  b: string[],
};

var myContainer: Container = {
  a: [],
  b: [],
};

var someStringArray = ['foo', 'bar'];

['a', 'b'].forEach((item) => {
  if (item === 'b') {
    myContainer[item as keyof Container] = someStringArray //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly A[] & string[]'
  }
});
```

I assumed the type of `instanceOfContainer[item as keyof Container]` would be `A[] | string[]` rather than `A[] & string[]`

Do you guys have a suggestion on how to overcome this?

Comment: Why are you not simply using `myContainer[item]`?

Comment: just delete `as keyof Container`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

```js
(['a', 'b'] as (keyof Container)[]).forEach((item) => {
  if (item === 'b') {
    myContainer[item] = someStringArray
  }
});
```